# Activate liveReload monitoring chrome-extension in google chrome launching from bash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, livereload

I'm trying to develope a bash script that launches google-chrome with a installed extension called LiveReload, which is used to monitor web changes. The point is when a web page is open you have to trigger LiveReload to start monitoring, and I want to do that automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: When chrome is launched after extension installation, the extension `LiveReload` or any other thing will launch automatically, what is exact use case?

Comment: @Sudarshan Extension is running, the icon appears, but when you want to monitor a webpage you have to click on it to activate `LiveReload`. That's what I want to do!

Comment: Thanks for asking this... while researching [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15538614/309233), I learned a whole lot more about the internals of the LiveReload extension! That's handy, because I'm trying to get it reloading an _extension_ I'm writing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is just to embed the [livereload.js](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js/raw/master/dist/livereload.js) script directly in your page(s) during development:

```html
<script src="js/vendor/livereload.js?host=localhost&port=32579"></script>
```

If you leave out the `host` and `port` params, LiveReload will infer them from the `src` attribute of the `script` tag. If you add the query param `LR-verbose` to the URL of *your page* (not the `livereload.js` tag), LiveReload will dump useful debugging info to the console attached to your page. E.g., `http://localhost:8080/nextbigthing/ideas.html?LR-verbose`

Since you're just manually loading the same file that the LiveReload extension would (either from its internal fallback copy, or from your LiveReload server), this behaves just as if you'd clicked the browser action button.